# How handle error related to loops in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

```
try {
  for (let i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    something
    try {
      send something
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR IN LOOP")
    }
  }
  console.log("YAY! LOOP finished")
} catch (e) {
  console.log("ERROR outside loop")
}
```

but when I run this code, even if there is an error in loop, `YAY! LOOP finished` is logged.
If there is an error in loop I just want to handle that error there and show it and not run `YAY! LOOP finished` after it.

Comment: Don't put `try/catch` inside the loop. Just use the outer one.

Comment: Or throw another error inside the inner `catch`.

Comment: If you are using async functions like ajax / promises you would need to use their `catch()` methods as the try / catch code will run before the async processes finish.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what logic you want to use. You're running the loop X times, say 10. What if there's 3 errors, but 7 cases where code execution proceeds normally? Do you want to stop execution at the first error? You'd use `break` like this:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    something();
    try {
      somethingElse();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR IN LOOP")
      break;
    }
  }
```

If you still want run the loop 10 times, but not log the final message in case there's an error, you'll have to set a flag like so:

```js
  let errorFlag = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    something();
    try {
      somethingElse();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR IN LOOP")
      errorFlag = true;
    }
  }
  if(errorFlag){
    // Error handling here, something like:
    // return;
    // throw new Error();
  }
  console.log("YAY! LOOP finished")
```